# Pandas Panel data - Linear interpolation of values based on rules

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, panel-data

I am working with a large panel data of financial values. Unfortunately, as I have taken the data from a data base, the information results to be a bit spotty (a lot of NaN values).  What I would like to do is to fill the missing values through linear interpolation.

The df looks like something like this (just putting two companies as an example):

```
         year     ticker     tot_assets 
0        2001      ANTQ             NaN
1        2002      ANTQ             NaN
2        2003      ANTQ           14.56
3        2004      ANTQ           14.99
4        2005      ANTQ             NaN
5        1999      AMFD            2.44
6        2000      AMFD             NaN
7        2001      AMFD            1.89
8        2002      AMFD             NaN
9        2004      AMFD            3.78
10       2005      AMFD            3.82
..       ...        ...             ...
```

As you can see from the example, sometimes the NaN starts at first year of available data - so I am not sure whether its best practice to insert a zero and interpolate from there or if it is possible to do backward linear interpolation.

Also, as you can see from the AMFD example, sometimes the data skips a few years, so it would be nice if we could that also into consideration.

The closest thing that I was able to come up with has been:

```
df['tot_assets'] = df.groupby(['tic'])['tot_assets'].fillna(method = 'bfill')
```

But of course this is not ideal because it doesn't really treat well the problems I have mentioned.

Furthermore, I have also tried to use and adapt interpolation documentation already available, but it didn't really work - mostly because I am not super experienced with Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
if (df.loc[i, 'ticker']==df.loc[i-1, 'ticker']) & (df.loc[i, 'fyear']==df.loc[i-1, 'fyear']+1):
    df.loc[i, 'tot_a_1'] = df.loc[i-1, 'tot_a']
else:
    df.loc[i, 'tot_a_1'] = None
```